# Is Ms. Makima a Demon?

Tags: chainsaw-man

In Chainsaw man, the character of Ms.Makima is quite strange, it seems to be a normal person who has a contract with a very powerful spirit/demon, and the particularities of this contract, the entity behind it, and other details of the character remain deliberately hidden.

However... there is something that makes me feel that there are more to Ms.Makima. There are two external features to human bonded to demons or human shaped demons that we can see on Denji and Power: sharp beast-like teeth and, in the case of Power, strangely pattern-colored eye pupils.

Ms.Makima have similarly colored pupils as Power, but with a different "pattern". Can be this a hint of her being a demon? Are there other hints or facts of this possibility?

Comment: https://chainsaw-man.fandom.com/wiki/Makima - Big spoilers here. No, seriously, if you're watching the TV show don't click here.

Answer (score 3):

Fairly large spoilers (and a graphic image from the series) from S1E8:

> The largest indication that Makima is a demon is when she and her entourage are ambushed on a train. Makima is shot in the head at point-blank range, along with the rest of her detail. However, Makima does not die from this wound and proceeds to use some sort of contract-like power to crush those attacking her team in Tokyo. No demon is ever shown in connection to said crushing ability. [image: Makima with fatal wounds]

Comment: *'"Tis but a graze"*